# Can we do some scaling argument in the presence of inhomogeneous norms?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

*Notation*:

- $B^n_R$ stands for the ball of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- $\hat{f}$ stands for the Fourier transform of $f$.

---

> **Question**. The following inequality holds true for all $f\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and all measurable $t=t(x)$ provided that $s>1/2$ ($^1$):
>   $$\tag{1}\left\lVert \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\, \hat{f}(\xi)e^{i(x\cdot\xi-t(x)\lvert\xi\rvert^2)}\, d\xi\right\rVert_{L^2_x(B^n_R)}\le C_s R^{\frac{1}{2}}\lVert f \rVert_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$
>   Can we use a scaling argument (or a variation of it) to show that the exponent of $R$ in the right hand side of (1) cannot be different from $1/2$?

It is mostly the presence of the inhomogeneous norm
$$\lVert f\rVert_{H^s}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lvert \hat{f}(\xi)\rvert^2\left( 1+ \lvert \xi\rvert^2\right)^s\, d\xi$$
which confuses me. However, I think that there should be a scaling explanation for that term $R^{1/2}$. Any hint is welcome.

---

($^1$) Cfr. Rogers-Vargas-Vega, [Pointwise convergence of solutions of the non-elliptic Schrödinger equation](http://www.uam.es/departamentos/ciencias/matematicas/AFA/AFA2004/files/2005-pub/RV05-converg.pdf), Theorem 3.

Comment: To who's intersted: I asked one of the authors, and she replied that she's inclined to think that indeed a scaling argument is not applicable here.